# Snake movement - follow every body part to the head path

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d-games, game-development

I'm trying to recreate Snake VS Block game on Unity,
currently I'm saving snake head position (adding it to the List) on every update, maximum length of list (saved positions) is equal to the snake body parts length, I'm removing first element if list size is more than snake size and adding new to the bottom of the list.

Snake head is moving by speed (Y) and mouse position (X), so you can control snake head movement horizontally but vertical movement is increased automatically time by time.

then i loop through the list and move snake part with the following logic:

```
SnakeParts[i].transform.position = Positions[Positions.Count-i];
```

Almost everything works properly but there is one problem, I can't keep fixed distance between the body parts, distance always depends on snake head `speed`, because elements of the `Positions` list is added on every frame (so distance between them is delta speed),

I'm looking for a better approach or improvement of my plan, please keep in mind that i want the body parts to follow the exact path of snake head

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You might be able to use the path strategy here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/120189/unity-method-to-get-a-vector-which-is-x-seconds-behind-another-moving-vector-a/120225#120225

Comment: @Ruzihm I don't think that this strategy will be helpful in this case because I have list of parts to follow each other but I'm gonna try to modify it for my needs

Comment: You need 2 things to do it. **1.** The path from where the head used to be when it was at the bottom of the screen, to where the head is now. I'm suggesting that you might be able to use the path strategy above to get that.  **2.** Loop thru the body parts and calculate the furthest point on the path that doesn't collide with any of the previous body parts. You can use spherecasting to do this. Then, place the body part there. Loop until you run out of path, or you run out of body parts.

Comment: @George did you managed to solve this problem? need help on this as i am facing same issue with a snake game.